# Where can I find a 110V/60Hz to 220V/50Hz voltage converter

Tags: power-supply, converter

I'm debugging a power supply issue with a product made for a 220V/50Hz power source.
Most made-for-USA step-up convertors provide 220V/60Hz (from a 120/60 USA mains supply).

I'd like to try providing 220V/50Hz (from a 120/60 USA electrical supply). Where can I buy such a converter?

Comment: I am sorry to say that shopping for devices is considered off topic for the stack exchange system. I wish you luck and I hope current feedback has already resolved this for you.

Comment: While this COULD be answered by shopping, it is *certainly* not a shopping question by any normal standard. Even though the suggested & logical solution is blindingly obvious to some it requires a little lateral thought. AND the suggested solution is still not a straight forward one. User did not spec power level. 230V 1A = say 25A at 12V. Wow. 2A = 50A. Which is hardish to do. There may be a better way than going to 12V at immense amps.

Comment: USER 48956 - The suggested solution using a 12V-230V inverter is viable at low wattages. What wattage do you need? At 12V you need perhaps 10 Amps per 100 Watts at 12V (some is lost due to inverter inefficiency). An alternative - less off-the-shelf but easy enough for a technician to implement, is...

Comment: Many low-V DC to HV-AC inverters use two stages. LVDC to HVDC then HVDC to HVAC. In many casesusing a 12-230 inverter you can implement an HVDC power supply and feed it into the DC HV rail in place of the LVDC/HVDC. It is far easier to implement a say 300 Watt DC power supply from 110V mains than to build a 12V, 30A power supply. As wattages increase the build rather than buy option gets more attractive, so it depends on your Wattage. If it's eg a power tool or heater building will probably be very attractive. For more help on this consider asking [here](http://www.piclist.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were willing to use a 12V DC supply you could use an inexpensive inverter designed to produce 220 V/50 Hz from a car battery. [Here](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=inverter%20for%20220V%2050%20Hz&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=7560301340852692315&sa=X&ei=qvb7Ts6JC-j40gHHpKTMAg&ved=0CI8BEPMCMAM) is one available for $38
which has a sign wave output and will handle 400 watts continuous, you did not state how much power you intend to draw.

Obviously this could be run from a standard 12 V bench supply with sufficient capacity, perhaps you have one already?

---

Added:        The above solution is "off the shelf" and is a good one for lower wattages. As wattage increases the current required at 12V becomes annoying to handle. 24V units are available but even that becomes a compromise.

A potential solution is to use an existing 12V-230V inverter but to disconnect the 12V-230V portion and just use the HVDC to HVAC portion.

Many low-V DC to High-V AC inverters use two stages.
 LVDC to HVDC then HVDC to HVAC.
 In many cases, using a 12-230 inverter you can implement an HVDC power supply and feed it into the DC HV rail in place of the LVDC/HVDC.
 It is far easier to implement a say 300 Watt DC power supply from 110V mains than to build a 12V, 30A power supply.

As wattages increase the build rather than buy option gets more attractive, so it depends on your Wattage. If it's eg a power tool or incorporates any sort of a heater, then  building will probably be very attractive.

If the above is enough of an answer and/or for more help on this consider asking [here](http://www.piclist.com)